# How to combine 2 arrays in a way that 1st element of array1 and 1st element of array2 and so on form a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays. The first contains the years like
`[2021,2020,2019,2018,2017]`
and the second contains number of occurrence like
`[2,3,1,3,3]`
I want the new array to look like this
`[[2021,2],[2020,3],[2019,1],[2018,3],[2017,3]]`
How to do this? Please help!
Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

```
const merge = (y, o) => {
    const res = [];
    y.forEach((year, i) =>
              res.push(`${year},${o[i]}`)
             );
    return res;
  };
  console.log(merge(allyears,farray))
```

I tried doing this and it works fine but the new array looks like this

```
["2021,3","2020,1","2019,2","2018,3","2017,3"]
```

How to make it look this way

```
[[2021,2],[2020,3],[2019,1],[2018,3],[2017,3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the length of 2 arrays is equal

So we have:

```js
const arr1 = [2021,2020,2019,2018,2017];
const arr2 = [2,3,1,3,3];

const combine = arr1.map((value, index) => ([value, arr2[index]]))

console.log(combine)
```

P/s: There are some other solutions that you can use, but only that one above